# How can i pass integer arguments to script file when using system command is used

Tags: c

When I am trying to give system command with arguments for running script file its not taking value but taking as string can i do that with out string operations as i commented the working sections or can i use any other command instead of system

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {
      unsigned char a = 1;
      unsigned short b = 100;
    #if 0
      char str[30],str1[10];
      strcpy(str, "sh shell.sh");//copying to str
      strcat(str, " ");

      sprintf(str1, "%d", a); //converting int a to string format
      strcat(str, str1);
      strcat(str, " ");

      sprintf(str1, "%d", b);
      strcat(str, str1);

      system(str);  //giving system command for running sh file
    #endif
      system("sh shell.sh a b");
      return 0;
    }


    Shell.sh

      echo -e ("No of arguments :$#")
      echo -e ("First argument  :$1")
      echo -e ("Second argument :$2")
```

Comment: Why not simply a single `sprintf` (or better, `snprintf` (or `sprintf_s` on Windows)) call to format the whole string in one line?

Comment: Regarding your question, as I understood it, you can't pass variables directly to the `system` call, you have to make a string containing everything and pass it to the `system` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really work it without using string arguments; that's what the underlying `exec*()` system calls take, and how `int main(int argc, char **argv)` works — the arguments are an array of strings.

You can simplify your code as:

```
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "sh shell.sh %d %d", a, b);
```

to do in one operation what you spread over 7 lines.  You should strictly check the result from `snprintf()`, though `str` is long enough for the values in the question.